# XSLT 1.0 and how can I find some keywords in Text

Tags: xslt

I would like to find some keyWords in Text by using XSLT 1.0

- contentText  : Marine weather forecasts, warnings, synopsis, and ice conditions. Hundreds of land and buoy station observations across and marine weather forecasts, warnings, synopsis, and ice conditions. Hundreds of land and buoy station observations across.
- KeyWords : "Marine weather, marine weather, Marine Weather"
- Delimiter : ,

The following code is only one Keyword works...but I would like to find Multiple KeyWords ("Marine weather, marine weather, Marine Weather")

```
<xsl:choose>
  '<xsl:when test="contains($contentText,$keyWordLower)">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($contentText,$keyWordLower)" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    <span class="texthighlight">
      <xsl:value-of select="$keyWordLower" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
    </span>
    <!--Recursive call to create the string after keyword-->
    <xsl:call-template name="ReplaceSections">
      <xsl:with-param name="contentText" select="substring-after($contentText,$keyWordLower)"/>
      <xsl:with-param name="keyWordLower" select="$keyWordLower"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </xsl:when> <xsl:otherwise>
    <xsl:value-of select="$contentText"/>
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Answer (score 3):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:param name="pKeyWords">
  <kw>Marine weather</kw>
  <kw>marine weather</kw>
  <kw>Marine Weather</kw>
 </xsl:param>

 <xsl:variable name="vKeyWords" select=
 "document('')/*/xsl:param[@name='pKeyWords']/*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
  <t><xsl:apply-templates/></t>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="text()" name="highlightKWs">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>

  <xsl:if test="not($vKeyWords[contains($pText,.)])">
   <xsl:value-of select="$pText"/>
  </xsl:if>

  <xsl:apply-templates select="$vKeyWords[contains($pText,.)]">
   <xsl:sort select="string-length(substring-before($pText,.))"
    data-type="number"/>
   <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="$pText"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="kw">
   <xsl:param name="pText"/>
   <xsl:if test="position()=1">
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($pText, .)"/>
    <span class="texthighlight">
     <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </span>
    <xsl:call-template name="highlightKWs">
     <xsl:with-param name="pText" select="substring-after($pText, .)"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
   </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the following XML document:**

```
<t>Marine weather forecasts,
warnings, synopsis, and ice conditions.
Hundreds of land and buoy station observations
across and marine weather forecasts, warnings,
synopsis, and ice conditions. Hundreds of land
and buoy station observations across.</t>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result:**

```
<t>
   <span class="texthighlight">Marine weather</span> forecasts,
warnings, synopsis, and ice conditions.
Hundreds of land and buoy station observations
across and <span class="texthighlight">marine weather</span> forecasts, warnings,
synopsis, and ice conditions. Hundreds of land
and buoy station observations across.</t>
```